# How to install pyaudio on replit?

Tags: python, pyaudio, replit

I have telegram bot that using SpeechRecognition pakage, and for SpeechRecognition I should install pyaudio pakage.

I was wondering how can i do that on [replit](https://replit.com/)? **is this possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After searching a lot, I am writing this for those who have the same problem as me**

Unfortunately, [replit](https://replit.com/) doesn't support PyAudio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Tools" -> "Packages" -> Search

Comment: I tried that, but getting this error : 

` ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio`
 `Failed to build PyAudio`
 `ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

`Failed to add packages, reverting the pyproject.toml file to its original content.
exit status 1`

Answer (score -1):

These options worked well for me, so you can try them:

1. Install the SpeechRecognition library.
2. Install PyAudio library.

If you already have Python installed, you can install these libraries from Command Prompt or Terminal. Thanks.

Comment: I know that , its different on https://replit.com/ .
 I want install this on replit